# same image on three different divs, load only once? how?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am mixing some javascript zoom (not much experience). I use

div image1 fit to screen/div

div (show together) 
div image1 zoomable div 
div image1 small zoom navigator div
div

when I click the one the other div hides and vice vera.

I don't know if the image is loaded three times, it loads immediately cause it runs locally on my pc. If the image is really loaded three times is there anything I can do to avoid it?

Thank you all,
in advance!

Comment: Sorry for the sample code, it looked different before posting, my fault for not previewing!

Comment: Browsers will cache images as long as the server gives them the right headers.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the web-developer tools built into Chrome or IE (and available as a plugin to Firefox) to determine whether the image is loading three times. But unless something strange is going on, it will only load once.

Comment: I put the script on a server yesterday for testing and I think it works great. I was worrying that my hidden divs would load the image again but didn't. Thank you a lot!